# F-Algebra confusion. I am unclear about its definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have been unclear about something in my lecture notes and hope somebody can help me to make sense of it. For a definition of an F-algebra, my notes state that it is a ring, R, containing (a copy of) the field F as a subring, where the following condition is met: cr=rc for all $r \in R,c\in F$, and also that the "copy" of $F \subseteq R$ is always given as {$cI_R | c \in F$} $\subseteq R$.

I am confused by the whole "copy" of F thing. For instance, among the examples of F-algebras, she has that, the ring of $M_{nxn}(F)$ is an F-algebra with F={$cI_{nxn} | c \in F$}.

I think that I am mostly confused about the "original" field and the "new" field, like if F=$\mathbb{R}$, in the matrix example, the F of the F-algebra is not $\mathbb{R}$ but instead the set of diagonal matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Another way to phrase the whole thing is that an $F$ algebra is a ring $R$ with a ring homomorphism $F\rightarrow R$ whose image is contained in the center of $R$. Since $F$ is a field, this homomorphism is necessarily injective (it's nontrivial because 1 goes to 1). The "copy" of $F$ is just its image under the homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that I am mostly confused about the "original" field and the "new" field, like if F=$\mathbb{R}$, in the matrix example, the F of the F-algebra is not $\mathbb{R}$ but instead the set of diagonal matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

In abstract algebra, the policy is usually to not distinguish between isomorphic objects. The idea is that the two things are, in all respects that are important for an algebraic object, identical.

You might think $\Bbb R$ and $\{I_n\cdot r\mid r\in \Bbb R \}$ look different, but in all respects of additional and multiplication, one set is just a relabeling of the other.

The thing is that we like to define F-algebras as if F were external, just as we do with vector spaces. The difference is that for algebras the map $f\mapsto 1_A \cdot f$ automatically is an isomorphism so that there is a natural copy of F inside A.